# How can I extract data from an enum and make it into an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

I have the following enum:

```
public enum ReferenceKey {
    MenuType             = 1,
    ReferenceStatus      = 2,
    ContentType          = 3
}
```

Is there a way that I can list this data as an IEnumerable with 
two fields. The first field for the number and the second for the 
string with a space between the first and second word as in:

```
1  "Menu Type"
2  "Reference Status"
3  "Content Type"
```

Comment: Have you tried Enum.GetNames and Enum.GetValues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can list this data as an IEnumerable with two fields. The first field for the number and the second for the string with a space between the first and second word

Why Not

**Solution 2: An Array as you wanted**

```
IEnumerable<ReferenceKey> v = 
                       Enum.GetValues(typeof(ReferenceKey)).Cast<ReferenceKey>();

string[] result = 
                  v.Select(x => (int)x + " \"" + x.ToString() + " \"").ToArray();
```

See it working

[image]

---

**Solution 2: A `Dictionary<int, string>`**

```
string[] str = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ReferenceKey));

Dictionary<int, string> lst = new Dictionary<int, string>(); 

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    lst.Add((int)(ReferenceKey)Enum.Parse(typeof(ReferenceKey), str[i]), str[i]);
```

See it working

[image]

---

**Solution 3: Another way of creating an `Dictionary<int, string>`**

```
Array v = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ReferenceKey));

Dictionary<int, string> lst = v.Cast<ReferenceKey>()
                               .ToDictionary(x => (int)x, 
                                             x => x.ToString());
```

Include `System.Linq` namespace for this

See it working

[image]

Comment: This looks very good. Is there a way I can make it so the strings appear as "Menu Type", "Reference Status" and "Content Type" ? Also could this be made to work for an enum that has values like 1,2,4,5 etc rather than just 1,2,3 ...

Comment: They are strings only. Do you want to store them with double quotes on both side?

Comment: @Angela: Look now. Its as you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Dictionary` together with the static `GetNames` and `GetValues` methods.

```
 var names = ReferenceKey.GetNames(typeof(ReferenceKey));
 var values = ReferenceKey.GetValues(typeof(ReferenceKey)).Cast<int>().ToArray();

 var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
 {
     string name = names[i];
     int numChars = name.Length;
     for (int c = 1; c < numChars; c++)
     {
         if (char.IsUpper(name[c]))
         {
             name = name.Insert(c, " ");
             numChars++;
             c++;
         }
     }
     dict[values[i]] = name;
 }
```

[GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx)
[GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx)

To get the formatting you specified, you could then do this:

```
string[] formatted = dict.Select(s => String.Format("{0} \"{1}\"", s.Key, s.Value)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I like this method as I can extend this to work for enums where the values are not 1,2,3 etc.  Actually I do have some enums with values not one after the other. For the string is there a way I could put a space in the middle of the strings if there is an uppercase as in "Menu Type"?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want it as a plain enumerable then do this:

```
var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ReferenceKey));
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ReferenceKey)).Cast<int>();
var pairs = names.Zip(values, (Name, Value) => new { Name, Value });
```

You get this result:

[image: Enumerable Pairs]

If you would like it as a dictionary, then do this:

```
var dict = pairs.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
```

You get this result:

[image: Dictionary Pairs]

If you want to add a space between each word you could add `.Select(n => Regex.Replace(n, "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim());` to the `names` variable definition.

With this spacing code you now get these results:

[image: Spacing Results]

Comment: Off topic but, how do you get generate those images of the variables content ?

Comment: @Nacereddine - I use LINQPad to do a lot of my "scratch" work and it allows you to dump variables in that table form. I then use OneNote to capture the screen and then Paint.NET to trim and save the images.

Comment: I did not know about LINQPad. Thanks for the very detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2):

A more generic approach for every enum type:

```
    static IEnumerable<string> EnumToEnumerable(Type x)
    {
        if (x.IsEnum)
        {
            var names = Enum.GetValues(x);

            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                yield return string.Format("{0} {1}", (int)names.GetValue(i), names.GetValue(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Invoke with

```
EnumToEnumerable(typeof(ReferenceKey));
```